# Apply Arab font only to letters not numbers

Tags: xaml, fonts, uwp-xaml, arabic

I am using GE Dinar Two font for arab data, in my uwp application.
The numbers are also changing to arab data.

For example:

Obtained result while applying font

Saturday 10 --> السبت ١٠

I need this result

Saturday 10 --> السبت 10

I need the font to be applied for the letters and not to numbers.
How can i achieve this, any help or suggestion is welcome

Comment: If the answer suits you can you keep me up to date since this is an interesting question which I think can come in handy in multiple situations

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do this in a single TextBox, since this is a control which handles the font family itself.

**Recommendet**

You can create a new font-family and add it like this: [Adding own fonts](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-fonts-in-windows-10-uwp-app/)

**Not recommended:**

Or you may want to add a keydown event and when the key is a number you just add a textBox right beside it. The easiest way to archieve this is I think to use the relativpanel and the use the sender name to align the new TextBox and give the new TextBox also a name, to recognize when if you have to add a new TextBox which takes letters instead of numbers. But this is really bad for user input, since he has to click on the number to edit it and so on. that is why you should go for solution 1. Because this is really bad programming style.